If sweep angles are high enough can supersonic wings use thick, rounded airfoils?
In lectures on aerodynamics, it's always emphasized that the effect of sweep is to lower the Mach number normal to the leading edge. In the context of supersonic flow, this ensure that the leading edge of the wing is experiencing a normal Mach number that is subsonic and thus is a "subsonic" leading edge. See this image from W.H. Mason's notes.

However, the question I run into is, assuming I have picked a sweep angle that appropriately ensures that the normal Mach is not just < 1 but also < M_cr of a relevant airfoil,  why can't we just use normal transonic airfoils of transport t/c (e.g., 10%) and perform aerodynamic analysis that is exactly like what you would do for a transonic transport aircraft traveling at M 0.8?
So for example, let's say I want to cruise at Mach 1.5, and I pick a sweep angle of 60 degrees, since cos(60)* 1.5 = 0.75, the "normal" Mach number is 0.75. Therefore,  I would have thought that I could use a NASA supercritical airfoil (which has a M_dd of > 0.75) and still have the transonic airfoil operate in a regime that is identical to if we were using the airfoil for a transport application. For example, see this example airfoil from the NASA supercritical publication. In particular, there should be very little wave drag on my wing here because the normal Mach is operating well below the M_dd of the airfoil.

But of course, I am clearly wrong. When I actually see airfoils for supersonic transports, they never do anything like what I said in the last paragraph. They are almost all very thin (t/c < 4%) and are much less rounded than subsonic airfoils, and this is true even when leading edges are highly swept.

OK, I figured out the answer. In essence, I am ignoring 2 drag components which only exist in supersonic flow.
In subsonic / transonic flow you have the following drag components: profile drag (which has a friction component and a pressure component called 'form' drag) and "induced" drag due to lift (aka"vortex"drag). In transonic flow, we add a new component, which is the wave drag from the shockwaves which form due to local acceleration of air beyond sonic velocity as it slows down. Notably, this wave drag component is a "near field" phenomenon in that it depends on the pressure distribution near the airfoil.
However, in supersonic flow, in ADDITION to all those components, you have two new "far field" components which are analagous to the "vortex" drag in subsonic flow: wave drag due to lift and wave drag due to volume. This wave drag is also due to shock wave formation, but NOT the same shockwaves we talk about in transonic flow, it is due to the need to push the air radially outward. This wave drag, specifically that due to volume, is ~ to t/c. Therefore, while sweeping the wing will help you control the local shockwave formation, you cannot use high t/c airfoils because it will adversely effect your far-field drag components.
TY to the Boeing aerodynamics fellow who helped me.

Not quite - wave drag is mostly pressure drag: Overpressure on forward-facing surfaces and suction on back-facing surfaces. Make the parts to which those surfaces belong thinner, and the pressure will have less of a horizontal component.

I'm a bit peaky but I'd call the additional drag at transonic speed simply "transonic drag" in order to keep it distinct from the proper wave drag that exists only at supersonic speeds. The transonic drag isn't only a pressure drag but also a viscous drag since it rises from the interaction between shock waves and boundary layer. Regarding the proper wave drag: I like the simpler explanation of @PeterKämpf here above.

You aren't entirely wrong.
Look at various fighters.  The F-5, F-16, and F-15 all use NACA 65A and 64A series.  The F-4 uses NACA 4-digit foils.  So all foils with rounded leading edges.
Likewise, most of the rest of the Century Series fighters use NACA airfoils with round LE (still very thin).
The thickness is still very thin -- typically 3-4% for each of these.
Supersonic planforms typically have low aspect ratio, sometimes all the way to a delta wing.  This gives the advantage of a large root chord, so that small t/c is multiplied by a large chord to give some dimensional thickness for the structures.  But rest assured, fighter wings are built very solid.
The XB-70 uses a 2% to 2.5% modified hex airfoil -- i.e. a truly sharp LE and TE.
The F-104 uses a 3.36% thick modified bi-convex airfoil -- another shape with a truly sharp LE and TE.
It depends on how fast you need to go and how much of your time you are going to spend there.
The Concorde and XB-70 spend almost all of their time at very high speed.
Fighters spend more time at a variety of speeds.  They only go their fastest during a dash.  Even for supersonic fighters, most aerial combat is done subsonically.  They need maneuverability -- which is helped with rounded leading edges.

Hm. But why so thin? If I want to travel at M1.5 and use 60 degrees of sweep, such that M_normal is 0.75, then I could get away with using a 10% t/c airfoil with M_cr > 0.75. Wave drag even with 10% thick airfoil should be low because we are < M_cr for the airfoil.

Drag divergence isn't really wave drag.  Drag divergence is a jump in drag caused by shocks on the upper/lower surface of an airfoil causing separation.  Wave drag is a separate phenemona.  You'll notice that many object's drag coefficient goes back down after it gets slightly supersonic.  Not as low as subsonic, but lower than transonic.  The thin wing will always be important to keep wave drag down.  Wave drag is about how much volume you're shoving through the air.
